# Radon-Nikodym Theorem for two positive measures

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, radon-nikodym

Let $\mu,\nu$ be two positive measures on $(X,\mathscr{A})$ and $\mu$ is finite.
If $\nu \ll \mu$, then does there exist a measurable function $f: X \to [0,\infty]$ such that
$$ \nu(E) = \int_E f d \mu,~\forall E \in \mathscr{A}? $$

I don’t know what happens when $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite.

Answer (score 0):

For the case where $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite the answer is yes provided $f$ is allowed to take the value $\infty$. See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760977/is-sigma-finiteness-unnecessary-for-radon-nikodym-theorem/3342557#3342557) answer.

Comment: What happens if $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite?

Comment: @Martin Argerami It still holds provided the function $f$ is allowed to take the value $\infty$ (which the OP has indicated is allowed in their setting). [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760977/is-sigma-finiteness-unnecessary-for-radon-nikodym-theorem) is another thread where this question is addressed.

Comment: As it is written, your answer is quoting the Wikipedia article which requires $\nu$ to be $\sigma$-finite. And I don't really see how the other answer contributes to yours; actually, it confuses things, because it says that the Wikipedia article is wrong, but then one would have to check what the article said back in 2016.

Comment: @Martin Argerami See the second answer in the thread I linked (the one with 1 up vote). The person who wrote it gives a detailed proof that $f$ exists in the case where $\nu$ is not $\sigma$-finite provided $f$ can take the value $\infty$.

Comment: Fair enough, but then link to [that specific answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3342557/22857).